# Сделать переменную глобальной для калькулятора jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы переменная total работала вне функции?
При суммировании результат переменной невидно. Как сделать переменную глобальной?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {   
 var $cbs = $('.calc__check');
 function calcUsage() {
  var total = 0;
  $cbs.each(function(){
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat($(this).val());
   }
  });
  console.log(total);
 }
 $cbs.click(function(){
  calcUsage();
 });
 calcUsage();

 $("input[name=send]").click( function () { // Событие нажатия на кнопку "Расчёт"
  var action = $("select[name=action]").val(); // Получаем значение действия, которое нужно выполнить
  var num = $("input[name=num]").val() * 1; // Переменная первого числа
  var size = $("input[name=size]").val() * 1; // Переменная второго числа
  var result; // Переменная результата
  if (action == 'Значки') {
   if (num >= 100 && num <= 130) {
    result = num * (180 + total + size); 
   }
   else if (num >= 131 && num <= 150) {
    result = num * (180*0.9 + total + size*0.9); 
   }
  }
  else if (action == 'Спортивные медали'){
   result = num * (300 + size);
  }
  $("input[name=result]").val(result); // записываем результат
 });



});
```

```css
.calc {
 background: #ccc;
 padding: 15px;
}

.calc__item {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.calc__label {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 align-items: center;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

.calc__input {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calc">
 <h2 class="block__title">
 КАЛЬКУЛЯТОР СТОИМОСТИ
 </h2>
 <div class="container">
  <form id="calc">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 calc__item">
     <label class="calc__subtitle">Что изготавливаем?</label>
     <select name="action">
      <option>Значки</option>
      <option>Спортивные медали</option>
     </select>
     <label>Особенности</label>
     <p>Могут повлиять на конечную цену</p>
     <label class="calc__label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="calc__check" value="11"> Более 3х цветов эмали
     </label>
     <label class="calc__label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="calc__check" value="11"> 3D элементы
     </label>
     <label class="calc__label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="calc__check" value="21"> Двухсоставное изделие
     </label>
     <label class="calc__label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="calc__check" value="11"> Трехсоставное изделие
     </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <label class="calc__text">Количество
      <input class="calc__input" type="text" name="num" placeholder="Введите количество" />
     </label>
     
     <label class="calc__input">Размер
      <input class="calc__text" type="text" name="size" placeholder="Введите размер" />
     </label>
     
     
     <input type="button" name="send" value="Расcчитать" />
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
     <label>Итого:</label><input type="text" name="result" placeholder="Ответ" />
     
     <div id="pay_price"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А вынести переменную за функцию не получается?

Answer (score 1):

Вынести переменную за функцию.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $cbs = $('.calc__check');
  var total = 0;

  function calcUsage() {
    $cbs.each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat($(this).val());
      }
    });

    console.log(total);
  }
  $cbs.click(function() {
    calcUsage();
  });
  calcUsage();

  $("input[name=send]").click(function() { // Событие нажатия на кнопку "Расчёт"
    var action = $("select[name=action]").val(); // Получаем значение действия, которое нужно выполнить
    var num = $("input[name=num]").val() * 1; // Переменная первого числа
    var size = $("input[name=size]").val() * 1; // Переменная второго числа
    var result; // Переменная результата
    if (action == 'Значки') {
      if (num >= 100 && num <= 130) {
        result = num * (180 + total + size);
      } else if (num >= 131 && num <= 150) {
        result = num * (180 * 0.9 + total + size * 0.9);
      }
    } else if (action == 'Спортивные медали') {
      result = num * (300 + size);
    }
    $("input[name=result]").val(result); // записываем результат
  });


});
```

```css
.calc {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
}

.calc__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.calc__label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.calc__input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calc">
  <h2 class="block__title">
    КАЛЬКУЛЯТОР СТОИМОСТИ
  </h2>
  <div class="container">
    <form id="calc">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 calc__item">
          <label class="calc__subtitle">Что изготавливаем?</label>
          <select name="action">
      <option>Значки</option>
      <option>Спортивные медали</option>
     </select>
          <label>Особенности</label>
          <p>Могут повлиять на конечную цену</p>
          <label class="calc__label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="calc__check" value="11"> Более 3х цветов эмали
     </label>
          <label class="calc__label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="calc__check" value="11"> 3D элементы
     </label>
          <label class="calc__label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="calc__check" value="21"> Двухсоставное изделие
     </label>
          <label class="calc__label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="calc__check" value="11"> Трехсоставное изделие
     </label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <label class="calc__text">Количество
      <input class="calc__input" type="text" name="num" placeholder="Введите количество" />
     </label>

          <label class="calc__input">Размер
      <input class="calc__text" type="text" name="size" placeholder="Введите размер" />
     </label>


          <input type="button" name="send" value="Расcчитать" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <label>Итого:</label><input type="text" name="result" placeholder="Ответ" />

          <div id="pay_price"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто вынесите `total` вне функции

```
var total;

$(document).ready(function() {  
    var $cbs = $('.calc__check');
    ...
}
```